# WCF JSON returns XML data!

Tags: wcf, web-services, json

I'm building a WCF REST Web service which should output JSON, but I'm getting XML.

I'm using ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json

Please help I search everywhere and I couldn't find the solution.

Note: I even tried the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914633/philosophy-of-webinvokeresponseformat-webmessageformat-json)

config file

```
<services> 
  <service name="TestService"> 
     <endpoint address="" 
               behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
               binding="webHttpBinding" 
               bindingConfiguration="webBinding" 
               contract="TestService" /> 
   </service> 
 </services> 
 <bindings> 
     <webHttpBinding> 
         <binding name="webBinding"> 
              <security mode="Transport"> 
              </security> 
          </binding> 
      </webHttpBinding> 
 </bindings>
```

Comment: I did try <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/> in the web.config file and didn't work!

Comment: Can I confirm that you are using WebServiceHost or WebHttpBinding?

Comment: I'm using WebHttpBinding. <services>
      <service name="TestService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
         binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="TestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

Comment: Can you add the endpointBehavior block to the config above too

Comment: Well I have it on <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TimeServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

Comment: Since you mention that you use the template, I'm assuming you're using the routes feature to define the service (`RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute(...))`). If this is the case, you can change the default response format by defining an *unnamed* endpoint behavior: <endpointBehaviors><behavior name=""><webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" /></behavior></endpointBehaviors>. However, if you say that you're using ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json in your operations, then I'd guess you have another problem (that should override the default value)

Comment: Aren't webHttp and enableWebScript mutually exclusive?

Comment: I turn off automaticFormatSelectionEnabled. <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />. Now it doesn't output xml format but it output in string format. Ex: "English". How do I display only the text (without quote)?

Answer (score 1):

Some things you need to check:

- The "name" attribute of your `<service>` element in web.config needs to match the **fully-qualified name** of the service class - if `TestService` is on namespace `MyNamespace`, then the service must be declared as `<service name="MyNamespace.TestService">` - in other words, it must match the name you have in the '.svc' file for your service
- Your endpoint declaration doesn't specify a `behaviorConfiguration` attribute; for WCF web endpoints, you need both to have the webHttpBinding **and** the a reference to a behavior which declares (in your case) `<webHttp />`
- Another option is to use the `WebServiceHostFactory` in the .svc file: `<% @ServiceHost Service="MyNamespace.TestService" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" Language="C#" debug="true" %>`. With this you don't need to have the service defined in config.

Comment: I'm not using .svc file. I using the WCF Rest template which don't need a .svc file. Beside that I did change the service name in the web.config and didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue because I had a tag like this;

```
<behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
```

after I remove

```
<webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
```

it is fixed. Maybe it is a bug. I am not sure.