# WCF Error 404 - Possibly the config file

Tags: wcf

I created a WCF project and i'm using the WCF Test Client, I got the returned message.  However, when I used the browser to the endpoint address, I received Error 404.  My code is shown below:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "UpdateTbl/{tblName}")]
public string UpdateTbl(string tblName)
{ ... }
```

The related code in the config file is below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
         <service name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1" >
<endpoint address="http://thehost:47423/Service1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfJsonRestService.IService1" >
</endpoint>
         </service>
     </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webHttp">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Please help if you can share your experience.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't configure service activation by providing a URL for the endpoint. The syntax you're using for the endpoint element is appropriate for a client configuration file, not a service. You must either use the URL of an SVC file for activation, or use a more sophisticated activation scheme, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292908/eliminate-the-svc-in-the-url-of-a-wcf-4-service-using-routes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658195/can-webinvoke-attributes-be-replaced-by-binding-configurations/5468125#5468125).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Being new in WCF, I am still unclear in the configuration.  I checked 2 addresses you provided, and tried use the syntax from there but got some additional errors.  If you can provide a URL for a simpler/better sample, I will greatly appreciate.